# Laravel 7 Search Bar using eloquent not displaying result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Im using laravel 7 and I'm trying to implement search in my project.
this is my controller search function code

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = Request::get('search');
    $posts = Post::table('posts')
        ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->paginate(5);

    return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

Here is the route

```
Route::get('/search', 'PostsController@search');
```

here is my search bar code

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-prepend">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the table in dashboard blade

```
@if(count($posts) > 0)
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <thead class="table-dark">
            <th>Entry#</th>
            <th>Consignee</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Uploaded By</th>
            <th>Date Uploaded</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            </thead>

        </tr>
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <tbody id="myTable" name="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td>{{$post->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$post->consignee}}</a></td>
                <td>{!!$post->body!!}</td>
                <td>{{$post->user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$post->created_at}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}/" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" href="#deletePost{{$post->id}}">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>{{$post->status}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
    </table>
    {{$posts->links()}}
@else
    <p> You have no entries</p>
@endif
```

My table looks like this
[image: example table]
I want it to look like this when I press the search button
[image: sample search result]
I don't know what seems to be the problem why the search is not displaying anything on the data table. Please show me how can I fix this. Thanks

Comment: why Post::table('posts')->where, it's just Post::where, try it please

Comment: I tried before but still the same. there is no result in search.

Comment: Please can you show where/how your trying to display it.

Comment: @Rwd there I edited the post.

Comment: Sorry, I meant can you show how your trying to use it in code i.e. the blade file where you're trying to use `$posts`.

Comment: you mean the table? Ok I will attach the table code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to define `table('posts')` in eloquent model class because model always set table name its class name (plural form). One more thing, when search query parameter is not set there's no need to apply where condition. If any value assign in search variable then it should be use where condition.

Please do it.

```
public function search (Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $posts = Post::when($search, function($sql) use ($search) {
            $sql->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
        })
        ->paginate(5);

    return view('dashboard', compact('posts'));
}
```

Comment: No need to define table('posts') in eloquent model class because model always set table name its class name (plural form). One more think when search query parameter is not set then no need to apply where condition, If any value assign in search variable then it should be use  where condition.

Comment: its now working the solution above is did the job

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem in Blade iteration. Kindly replace count($posts) with $posts->total() method. Because $posts are paginated data object not array list.

```
@if($posts->total() > 0)
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <thead class="table-dark">
            <th>Entry#</th>
            <th>Consignee</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Uploaded By</th>
            <th>Date Uploaded</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            </thead>

        </tr>
        <tbody id="myTable" name="myTable">
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$post->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$post->consignee}}</a></td>
                <td>{!!$post->body!!}</td>
                <td>{{$post->user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$post->created_at}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}/" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" href="#deletePost{{$post->id}}">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>{{$post->status}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{$posts->links()}}
@else
    <p> You have no entries</p>
@endif
```